# Supply Test Instruction when submit App to Apple

Tags: iphone, app-store

I am going to submit my App to Apple for review, but in order to use my App, they need to register their ID via web interface and their Device ID.

Where can I supply test instruction for testing team?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give it in Review Guidelines field

Answer (score 0):

If you have a service requiring a login, you can put login info to a demo account in the Review notes in iTunes Connect.

But the App store rules or guidelines appear to prohibit apps that require a user to submit identifying personal ID or device ID information in order to run.